# asp.net Page.PreviousPage Scope

Tags: asp.net, iis, scalability, cross-posting

I am using ASP.net 3.5 
I have a page cross posting to another page which is unfortunately a requirement of my design.
In order to access the values on the previous page which did the submission i define some set/get elements for the 3 values I need ie

```
public string sDesc { get { return Description.InnerText; } }
```

Then on the page being crossposted to access them like

```
string Desc = ((AddNewBlogXSL)PreviousPage).sDesc;
```

assuming I have

```
<%@ PreviousPageType VirtualPath="~/AddNewBlogXSL.aspx" %>
```

on said cross posted page.

My question is the scope of PreviousPage. If I am using a server farm or webgarden is previous page available if i hit a different process or server? No guarantees my cross post hits the same server or process.

Also as a side note efficiency and scalability are important concerns for me, is there anything in this method that would really impact a high volume site?

Comment: This question is related to the solution to another question I had at 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6051898/asp-net-not-posting-back-to-correct-page

Comment: It should work as per this: http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t120522-previouspage-property-and-web-farms.html